# Compiling scss into css using node-sass with Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I'm trying to compile my scss file into css file using node-sass , I already know how to do this with Command line.
I have this `npm-script` In my `package.json` file :

```
"scripts": {
"scss": "node-sass --watch fileName/scss -o FileName/css"
}
```

and when I run :

```
npm run scss
```

it works fine.
What I want to know is how to use (from the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) project page) :

```
var sass = require('node-sass');

sass.render({
  file: scss_filename,
  [, options..]
}, function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
```

I try this in my `app.js` :

```
var sass = require('node-sass');

sass.render({
  file: __dirname + '/scss/style.scss',
  outFile: __dirname + '/css/style.css',
});
```

but it's not working, I have little experience with this and I can use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within the same documentation you linked to

```
sass.render({
    ...
    outFile: yourPathTotheFile,
  }, function(error, result) { // node-style callback from v3.0.0 onwards
    if(!error){
      // No errors during the compilation, write this result on the disk
      fs.writeFile(yourPathTotheFile, result.css, function(err){
        if(!err){
          //file written on disk
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

the `sass.render()` doesn't write to the file, it only passes the `result` to a callback. You need to write it yourself using `fs` as in the example above.

Comment: What the `fs` is here? I get an error that `fs is not defined`. What it should refer to?

Comment: [node file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) add `const fs = require('fs');`